# Memory Management in Objective-C when dealing with NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone

In Instruments the tempPlayer object is showing a leak. In this code, in every for loop I keep on allocating a new tempPlayer instance, set its playerCode variable with a string and add it to an NSMutableArray in each iteration. Instruments shows me a leak in the alloc statement. Is there any way to prevent tat leak in the tempPlayer object ?

```
 for(int i = 0 ; i < [homeLineupArray count] ; i++) {   
    NSArray * tildeSeperator = [[homeLineupArray objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@"~"];

    [self.tempPlayer release];
    self.tempPlayer = [[LineUpsPlayer alloc] init];
    tempPlayer.playerCode = [tildeSeperator objectAtIndex:0];

    [matchLineUp.homeTeamPlayingEleven addObject:tempPlayer ];
}
```

Thanks
Harikant Jammi

Answer (score 1):

I would simply do this.

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < [homeLineupArray count] ; i++) {   
    NSArray *tildeSeperator = [[homeLineupArray objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@"~"];

    LineUpsPLayer *player = [[[LineUpsPlayer alloc] init] autorelease];
    player.playerCode = [tildeSeperator objectAtIndex:0];
    [matchLineUp.homeTeamPlayingEleven addObject:player];
}
```

You can also replace your loop with this:

```
for (NSString *lineup in homeLineupArray) {
    NSArray *tildeSeparator = [lineup componentsSeparatedByString:@"~"];
    ...
}
```

You don't usually want to save each item while iterating through an array to an instance variable since it keeps changing and you only reference it in the method.

Comment: The autorelease there should fix the leak - but I'd argue that it's better to explicitly release after adding to the array (although in practice its unlikely to make a big difference in this case - its more a matter of a style).

Answer (score 0):

Things may depend on how do you declare your `tempPlayer` property in your class (and as it looks that it is temporary object, consider do you need a property accessor for it?)

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < [homeLineupArray count] ; i++) {   
    NSArray * tildeSeperator = [[homeLineupArray objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@"~"];

    [self.tempPlayer release]; // Decrease retain count 
    self.tempPlayer = [[LineUpsPlayer alloc] init]; // retain count increase by 1 or 2
    tempPlayer.playerCode = [tildeSeperator objectAtIndex:0];

    [matchLineUp.homeTeamPlayingEleven addObject:tempPlayer]; // retain count increase
}
```

So as you can see you retain your object more times then you release it so it eventually leaks. Probably your code may be rewritten this way:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < [homeLineupArray count] ; i++) {   
        NSArray * tildeSeperator = [[homeLineupArray objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@"~"];

       LineUpsPlayer* tempPlayer = [[LineUpsPlayer alloc] init]; // object's retain count is 1
        tempPlayer.playerCode = [tildeSeperator objectAtIndex:0];

        [matchLineUp.homeTeamPlayingEleven addObject:tempPlayer]; // container takes ownership of the object
        [tempPlayer release]; // we do not need to own this object as it is in container now
    }
```

Comment: Looks like we reached the same conclusion at the same time ;-)
Probably `tempPlayer` should be made a local variable, too.

Comment: Yes, forgot to add tempPlayer declaration

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the property, `tempPlayer`, use a local variable, and release after adding to the array:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < [homeLineupArray count] ; i++) {   
    NSArray * tildeSeperator = [[homeLineupArray objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@"~"];

    LineUpsPlayer* tempPlayer = [[LineUpsPlayer alloc] init];
    tempPlayer.playerCode = [tildeSeperator objectAtIndex:0];

    [matchLineUp.homeTeamPlayingEleven addObject:tempPlayer ];
    [tempPlayer release];
}
```

The array retains the objects you add - that's why you need to release the temporary object too.

Answer (score 0):

As said above, I normally use a local variable to populate the mutable array. In other cases Instruments didnt show me any leak. So is this the right way to go about ?

```
for(int i =0 ; i <  ([arrayOfHomePlayers count]); i++ ) //creating home players detials object
{

    localString = [NSMutableString string];
    localString = [arrayOfHomePlayers objectAtIndex:i] ;
    NSArray * localPlayersArray = [localString componentsSeparatedByString:@"~"] ;
    localPlayerPosition = [ [PlayerPosition  alloc] init] ;

    NSArray * playerNameArray = [[localPlayersArray objectAtIndex:0] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] ;
    localPlayerPosition.globalID   = [localPlayersArray objectAtIndex:1];

    [(teamFormationDetails.homePlayerList) addObject:localPlayerPosition] ;
    [localPlayerPosition release] ;
```

Comment: you do not need  localString = [NSMutableString string];

Comment: As Vladimir says, you don't need the `localString = [NSMutableString string];` - and that will cause a leak.
You'll need to declare `localString`, though. What are you doing with `playerNameArray` ?

Comment: won't [NSMutableString string] return autoreleased object?

Comment: yeah, sorry, scratch that - there's no leak there - but it is redundant.

Comment: Does the Instruments tool give out false positives sometimes? Because in all methods i have used local variables, it dint show a leak only in this function its showing leaks. Any clues?

Harikant Jammi

Answer (score -1):

First, you could change the release to an autorelease and move it to the line after the self is assigned.

Second, the addobject is adding it to a collection which retains it, and I don't see you removing it from that collection, so that's your 'leak'.  However, I'm not sure there even is a leak, if you intended to leave it in the collection.

Comment: It's only a one time leak, though, it doesn't leak more each time around.  I have updated my answer to fix that.

Comment: changing to an autorelease will just delay when the release happens. It won't impact the leak

Comment: "It's only a one time leak, though" - that depends how the property is implemented - which we can't see.
Also, the OP doesn't say that it leaks on every iteration - just that Instruments shows a leak at the alloc.

Comment: I have declared the property like this 
@property (nonatomic, retain) LineUpsPlayer * tempPlayer ;

Comment: @unknown - so it will continue to hold its reference after the last iteration (but the other iterations should be fine)